# Easy Hardy Weinberg Equilibrium

Tags: genetics, statistics, allele, biostatistics, hardy-weinberg

[image]

Hi
My friend and I get 2 different answers to this question. I would like to know how to calculate the value of q. My friend says that 500/1500=q because there are 500 recessive alleles in the population and there are 1500 alleles in total. I say that p2= 500/1500 and P is the square root of that value and  q+p=1 but we both get different answers.  Please let me know which way is correct. Thank you guys in advance

Answer (score 0):

P=(250 × 2 + 500)/1500 = 0.66
Q=500/1500 = 0.33
Your friend was right, you miscalculated P because forgot to add the alleles coming from the heterozygotes.